# How to force cloud sync on GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, epic-games-launcher

So I'm playing the epic games version of GTA V on Geforce Now, and I always manually and automatically save after every mission. However, when I download it again the cloud sync seems behind and I've lost a lot of progress and have to do some missions again. Is there a way to force cloud sync or something like that? Or check what is being synced?