# GTA V reverting cloud saves?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, epic-games-launcher

As I said in my last [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/377126/how-to-force-cloud-sync-on-gta-v), my cloud saves were behind on my missions. Since I play GTA V on Geforce Now, my data always gets erased to I rely on the cloud to save my games. However, I noticed that when I reinstalled the epic version of GTA V, the saves were behind a lot. So I played for a while more, and then reinstalled again, and then they were also behind.

But the thing is, I checked the social club before I installed it and it showed the right amount of progress, but when I installed gta the progress was reverted on both gta and social club! I'm wondering what's going on, and is there a way to solve this? Could it be a problem with the Epic games save?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options here:

- The Rockstar Games Launcher was closed as soon as the game was terminated, so the RGL didn't had the chance to upload the saves

  - To prevent this in the future, manually open the Rockstar Games Launcher for a couple of seconds to make sure that your saves are uploaded to the cloud
- There was a conflict between the local and remote saved data, and you chose to keep the one that had the least progress

  - When there is a cloud data conflict, make sure that the correct saves are selected

When it comes to the game progress shown on your Social Club profile, this information is sent by the game every couple of minutes while you are playing. Because of this, the information shown is fetched from the last saved game that you used.

Sadly, there is no way to recover your saved game from both of this outcomes. In the first one, the saved game was never uploaded, and in the second one, the saved game was removed permanently from the cloud and locally.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep the first option in mind. However, there is no local save game for the second one because everything is erased. Also, is there a way to see if my saves are uploaded? I was relying on the Social Club, but since you said it is only sent by the game it isn't a valid way to check.